# AngularJS: Unable to receive data from $http.post()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am able to:

- Send text data from text boxes in HTML form to Controller using
  ng-model and ng-submit directives.
- Send this data from controller to Service.

**Problem:**
 - From Service, I am not able to access my data in Server.js file and
   thus as a result I am not able to insert the data into MySQL table.

My AngularJS Service here uses built-in angularJS $http service to post the data.

I just started learning AngularJS, and came across this problem.

I have commented at appropriate places for ease.

**HTML form** code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  ng-submit="submit()">

            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">ID:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Enter ID" ng-model="text1">

            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title" ng-model="text2">
```

**Controller** code:

```
    (function() {
        var newArticleController = function ($scope, customersService, appSettings) {   
                $scope.list = []; // will pass this list
 //init function: customerService is a Service

                function init() {
                    customersService.postArticle($scope.list)
                        .success(function() {
                                console.log('post promise success!') //This is not printing!!!!!
                        })
                        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        })
                    }
    //on submit: init() is called
                $scope.submit = function() {
                    if ($scope.text1 && $scope.text2) {
                        $scope.list.push(this.text1)
                        $scope.list.push(this.text2)
                        init()
                        } } };

        angular.module('customersApp')
          .controller('newArticleController', newArticleController);
    }());
```

AngularJS **Service** code:

```
(function(){ 
    var customersService = function($http) {
        this.postArticle = function(dataRcvd) {
            console.log('service called');
            console.log(dataRcvd); //This is printing

            return $http.post('/newArticle', JSON.stringify(dataRcvd))
        }

    }
    angular.module('customersApp').service('customersService', customersService);
}())
```

**Server.js** *(problem comes in this part)*

```
 var express = require('express'),
 var app = express();

    var knex = require('knex')({
        //...
    });
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

    app.post('/newArticle', function(req, res) {
            console.log('reached here: server.js')  //This is printing 

            ---> **//HOW TO ACCESS 'dataRcvd' here ???**    
    })
```

*I am a newbie, so if any edits are required then please help me out.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add body-parser to your server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
var app = express();

**var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json**
```

Then you can use

```
req.body
```

to access the data.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot I am able to get the data in server.js . Now, in controller `customersService.postArticle($scope.list) .success(function() { console.log('post promise success!') }) .error(function(data, status, headers, config) { })` On success, post promise success should be printed too. Why is it not printing?

Comment: Do you send an answer from your server? e.g. res.send("{"success":true}");

Answer (score 0):

Try by updating your code as below.

Step 1- Add the "body-parser" first.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

Step 2- and include middleware as

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Step 3- Try to access data as follows.

```
app.post('/newArticle', function(req, res) {
        console.log('reached here: server.js')  //This is printing 

        ---> **//HOW TO ACCESS 'dataRcvd' here ???**  
          console.log(req.body);

          res.end();    
})
```

So, to resolve the promise at angular end please update your service code as follows.

```
 angular.module('customersApp').service('customersService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {


    this.postArticle = function(dataRcvd) {
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       console.log('service called');
       console.log(dataRcvd); //This is printing
      $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: '/newArticle',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
       data: JSON.stringify(dataRcvd)
       }).success(function (data) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
       }).error(function (msg) {
          deferred.reject(msg);
       });
       return deferred.promise;
    }
 }]);
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot
I am able to get the data in server.js .  Now, in controller
`customersService.postArticle($scope.list)
     .success(function() {
       console.log('post promise success!')
     })
     .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     })` 
On success, post promise success should be printed too. Why is it not printing?

Comment: I have updated the my initial solution, please try that.

Comment: I will look into it and get back to you. Thank you.